# query to search a field in a database based on HTML form content

Tags: php, mysql, html

I need a query that will allow me to enter a code into a form in HTML and then search that code against a field in my database and then echo the the fields of the database out on a new page.

Can anyone help i don't know where to start, I've created the database and have php script that connects to the database which is working perfect, can someone tell me the query i would need to do this and the code that links to the html form.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create an HTML form that submits some text:

```
<form method="post">
<input name="string" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

When you receive it in your PHP file, query the database with `LIKE` :

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query('
    SELECT `column` FROM `table`
    WHERE `column` LIKE "%'. addslashes($_POST['string']) .'%"');
?>
```

The addslashes may be not needed if you have automatic escaping turned on (not recommended)

Good Luck!